# Xamarin.Forms Segoe Icon Code Binding in XAML UWP project Xamarin Native Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm trying to bind the Code of a Segoe Icon Font from my code to a Native `TextBlock` I added on my view But I get Back the Hexadecimal code of the icon instead of the Icon.

I don't understand why it behaves as such, here is the code:

```
<win:TextBlock Text="&#x1f47a;" FontSize="50" />
```

In the code snippet above I have my Icon displayed as I wish, But when I put that same Icon code in a Variable and Bind it to My View I don't get the icon anymore.

C#:

```
public string Icon { get; set; } = "&#x1f47a;";
```

XAML:

```
<win:TextBlock Text="{Binding Icon}" FontSize="50" />
```

Where as, When I add the code directly to XAML, I get the icon directly.
I guess Binding causes the XAML not to interpret the code as hexadecimal but as a `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you cannot use the XML escape sequence, but there is another catch - the unicode code for this Emoji is too high, so it cannot be represented using `\u` escape sequence, so it parses only the first four numbers as one character and appends the "a" as another character.

You can search the Emoji up on [Graphemica](http://graphemica.com/) for example and you can see it can be represented by a pair of unicode characters - 0xD83D 0xDC7A.

So the correct code would be:

```
public string Icon { get; set; } = "\ud83d\udc7a";
```

An alternative notation would be using the `\U` escape sequence, but it requires you to add three additional zeros before the emoji code (to make up eight-number code).

```
public string Icon { get; set; } = "\U0001F47A";
```

[image: Emoji]

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

XML (so also XAML) have different escape symbol than c#, so instead of your icon escaped as in XAML

```
public string Icon { get; set; } = "&#x1f47a;";
```

use C# escape symbol:

```
public string Icon { get; set; } = "\u1f47a";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but it doesnt work, instead I see a funny character (that is : a sqaure and letter "a")

Comment: are you sure you're setting a font which supports these icons?